# Jenkins - Disappears all jobs after restart

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-agent

The jenkins version is :

```
<version>2.186</version>
  <installStateName>RESTART</installStateName>
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
```

All jobs disapperad after restart jenkins : `sudo service jenkins restart`

`/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` includes them. The config file has no conflict. I have checked it using an xml validator.

How can I fix it? There is no job in jenkins dashboard.

Comment: Do you have exceptions in the Jenkins master logs?

Comment: yes, `java.io.IOException: Permission denied
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
 at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:142)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temporary file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/my-job` . There are too many permission errors

Answer (score 0):

Either option will work

1) 
choose option reload configurations from disk (Manage Jenkins/Reload Configuration from Disk).
 Or

2) Can you try to install Stable Jenkins and import all jobs n folder structure to new jenkins folder structure.
Hope that might help if by mistakenly someting is courupted or deleted in current folder structure of jenkins. 
I had same issue I solved it using above method

Comment: I have tried to reload from disk, there is no difference. Can I set JENKINS_HOME manually? I list all env variables,  JENKINS_HOME is unset

Comment: Yes. you can set it And then restart Jenkins service.

Comment: <url>/systeminfo(jnekins->manage jenkins->system information) includes below variables: `/HOME /var/lib/jenkins
JENKINS_HOME /var/lib/jenkins`. But I cannot see these values in server. How can I add?

Comment: Can you Give me access to Jenkins Master I will fix It. copy all Jenkins folder First and then provide  me access.

Comment: Did you tried no 2 option which i suggested that might help you to solve this issue faster and if it worked then you can copy new config.xml file to old jenkins server .

Answer (score 0):

I would first check folder permissions:

```
stat /var/lib/jenkins/jobs
stat /var/lib/jenkins
```

Then I would change permissions if needed:

```
chown -R your_user /var/lib/jenkins
```

You will need to restart Jenkins and maybe reboot the machine.